# Cannot connect to MSSQL with Docker via VSC (MacOS)

Tags: sql-server, macos, docker, visual-studio-code

I am trying to connect to MSSQL via Visual Studio Code with installed mssql extension. I did pull and run SQL Server 2017 container image with Docker and I am trying to make a connection, although I do get an error:

> mssql: Failed to connect: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)
>   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Undefined error: 0 at System.Data.SqlClient.SN

The container image is running - I did log on to MSSQL through terminal, but I can't with Visual Studio Code. Do I have to provide an instance as well? Where I can find it - cannot find it on docker inspect statement.

Did you guys have similar problem and maybe found a solution?

Comment: can you share your connection string

Comment: Please share the connection string and also how you ran the sql container, please share the complete command

Comment: I run the sql container with the following comand

docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=<MyPass>' -p 1433:1433 --name sqlcontainer1 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux

For the connection I was trying both with localhost and with the internal IP of the host and still nothing

Server=localhost; 
User Id=SA;
Password=MyPass;

Comment: When I run docker inspect I do get

 "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "1433/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "1401"
                    }
                ]
            },

Does this mean that I cannot connect to sql server outside of the container?  Where I can check whether I can connect to container remotely?

Comment: Update
I did connect to the sql server via SQLPro for MSSql, although I did it through port 1401. Anyway I still cannot connect via VSC.

Comment: Kill the existing containers and try the command again

Comment: Yeah I did it. I've tried with different containers as well. It seems like with VSC I cannot explicitly set a port through which I am trying to connect. Like it's always default 1433. Maybe I used a wrong connection string but localhost,1401 or localhost:1401 did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I managed to solve the problem. I do connect to sql server container on 1401 port (localhost,1401 on VSC), but apparently when you start a container you need to change the password for sa. Rookie mistake :) Thanks for trying to help